# How to change your team name Counter Strike Global Offensive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was wondering how to change the team name just for my computer so it won't be for all players in that game.

`mp_teamname_1 team` does not work; it does not change the name.

Answer (score 1):

The command is correct, but it has to be done on the **server** you're playing on (or remotely using RCON). Also the team names and other settings of this kind are only visible to spectators.

If you're using those commands on your computer they would only work if you hosted the game locally. Joining a server and using them locally does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's `mp_teamname_1 "team"` and `mp_teamname_2 "team"`